# Transfering files using ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, file-transfer

I've found the following command pretty convenient for transferring files to servers I have ssh access to:

```
cat myfile.txt | ssh my.host.edu "cat > myfile.txt"
```

Is there a similarly convenient command for bringing files to my local computer?
If it would make it any easier, I don't mind installing command line utilities from the standard Ubuntu repos.

Comment: What is wrong with `scp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one :

```
ssh my.host.edu "cat myfile.txt" > myfile.txt
```

But if you want to do file transfert overt `ssh`, use `sftp` which is a tool who is dedicated to this.

Answer (score 7):

It's installed by default, it comes with `openssh-client`:

```
scp user@my.host.edu:/path/to/myfile.txt /path/to/local/myfile.txt
```